# post parameter (array) undefined when assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've got this on my `node` server:

```
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.post('/jetsi', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  let filesFolders = req.body.fs;

  for (var i = 0, len = filesFolders.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(filesFolders[i]);
  }
  return res.status(200).send("test");
});
```

the problem is when I try to store `req.body.fs` to my variable (`filesFolders`)... it `undefined`!
If I debug my server, I see the data correctly, but I can work with it... why? look at the picture:

[image]

I call to the server on a `react` app like this:

```
const url = config.API_URL + 'jetsi';
axios({
  url: url,
  method: 'post',
  data: { fs: this.state.itemsToDownload },
  responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

The idea is to create a zip file (and download it). So from a react app I send a post request with an array witch I need to get on my node app to make my zip file. Any idea what is happening?

any clue? thank's in advance

Comment: what does the `fss` return in `console.log(fss[i]);` ? Also try changing the `let` to `var` in `let filesFolders = req.body.fs;`

Comment: `console.log(fss[i])` was something I tried `fss=req.body.fs` I forgot to remove before posting now it should be `console.log(filesFolders[i]);` I'll edit now.
I tried with var instead of let but same happens

Comment: I am quite sure that your error is here `let filesFolders = req.body.fs;`  Try just `req.body` instead of `req.body.fs`. If that doesn't work, write a console log after each `var` declaration to see in more depth where it breaks exactly.

Comment: I see the problem. If I console.log the variable... the data is there... is WebStorm witch is not getting the data!! when debugging... It can't show me the real value of the variable! strange!

Comment: try using `Atom` or `Brackets` or any other IDE. Also try running the thing in Chrome, I find the debugging tools a bit better than other browsers.